# How to send manually a HTTP POST request... and get back the actual website

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, developer-tools

I am debugging a form in a web application, and I need to disable Javascript to see how the server will respond... except that the form's "Submit" button is wired to a Javascript function which submits it by calling the POST URL. How can I trigger this HTTP POST call manually?

I have looked at browser add-ons like RESTClient or REST Easy... but they seem to be oriented to debugging REST apps, and thus, only return the raw HTML, which in my case has hundreds of lines of scripts, headers, etc., and it's hard to wade through all of that cruft to see the actual response given by the server. Is there any way to do that and get back the actual rendered web page, just as if it was a client submitting the form? (only, you know, without executing the Javascript first).

Comment: can you paste raw HTML in notepad and save it as html file?
or, if you are looking for specific string, maybe you can search for it in the output given by POST request.

Comment: Have you tried Postman for Chrome? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction

Comment: Have tried Postman, thanks. The thing is, the form has lots of fields (including hidden ones), and I'd have to copy by hand all of its parameters to Postman to reconstruct the POST request. I'd rather do it in-browser: I navigate to the site, fill out the form, disable the Javascript... and send. This way I can be sure that I'm not missing out anything by accident.

Comment: you can use environmental variables in postman, pull your data from a json file in your local machine which contains your form data.https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments

Comment: @Roljhon: okay, but I'd still have to copy by hand all the fields of the form I'm debugging. (I should clarify that I didn't write this web app, so I don't know exactly how it works internally).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: you want to turn off javascript to prevent what, exactly? And then you want to submit the form "manually", i.e. without hitting the submit button? But your manual POST would do exactly the same thing as the submit button?

Comment: That's massive work, however, I'm not getting why you are checking a server response when javascript is disabled? I think the server will still respond in the same manner, however the form submission which inlines with a javascript will prevent that to happen. So I'm not sure why are you doing this :D

Comment: Okay, let me explain: I'm trying to find out if this web app performs server-side validation in a form too, in addition to client-side validation. The server side code is quite involved, so I thought that it would be simpler to just disable the client-side validation (that is, JS), submit the form and see what happened (instead of wading through all the source code). I didn't realize that, in the modern web development world, something as simple as submitting a POST form without JS was practically nuclear physics... :-D